# How to modify GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to show a rectangular area rather than circular

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, blur, gpuimage, imagefilter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify a GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to operate over a rectangle instead of a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257429/how-do-i-modify-a-gpuimagegaussianselectiveblurfilter-to-operate-over-a-rectangl)

There's a similar question at [How do I modify a GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to operate over a rectangle instead of a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257429/how-do-i-modify-a-gpuimagegaussianselectiveblurfilter-to-operate-over-a-rectangl) but the answer is not complete so I am reposting. Let me rephrase the question. I am trying to use the GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter from the most awesome GPUImage library by Brad Larson. The only thing I need changed is shape of the "clear" area that appears on image. I looked at the code and the following line decides which color to apply to the pixel depending upon how far it is from the center of the "clear" area :

```
 gl_FragColor = mix(sharpImageColor, blurredImageColor, smoothstep(excludeCircleRadius - excludeBlurSize, excludeCircleRadius, distanceFromCenter));
```

What do I change in the SHADER_STRING so I get a rectangular area? Also, the rectangular area may also have rotation/scaling so the filter needs to adjust the "clear" area accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes it is a duplicate post but the other post is no way near to any concrete answer and/or direction to the answer so I reposted. thanks for checking!

Comment: I am unsure why this has been marked as a dupe when the other question does not answer the question correctly? Am I missing something?

Comment: Gill's answer was indeed incorrect there, so I've added an answer of mine that explains in detail what you need to do here.

Comment: As far as rotation and other customizations, I highly recommend tinkering with the math in the fragment shader yourself to provide the needed modifications. You'll be far better off if you learn the appropriate shading language yourself, rather than just have someone hand you the results.